# Codigo de Barras PDF417

Tags: php, html, angularjs, excel

Buenos dias comunidad,

Tengo una pequeña pregunta respecto a un lector que estoy usando en mi proyecto para reconocer documentos de identidad.

> PDF417 es uno de los códigos de barras que se puede utilizar para
>   imprimir el franqueo aceptado por el Servicio Postal de los Estados
>   Unidos e igualmente es uno de los tres códigos admitidos en el
>   estándar de Bar Coded Boarding Pass (Pase de a Bordo Codificado en
>   Barras) de la industria aérea como el código de barras 2D para la
>   emisión de tarjetas de embarque impresas.​ También fue seleccionado
>   por el Departamento de Seguridad Nacional estadounidense como la
>   tecnología de zona de lectura mecánica para las licencias de conductor
>   compatibles con RealID y tarjetas de identificación emitidas por el
>   estado. La empresa de transporte FedEx lo usa en las etiquetas de los
>   paquetes que transporta. Fuera de Estados Unidos, es usado por la
>   Registraduría Nacional del Estado Civil de Colombia para la emisión de
>   la Cédula de Ciudadanía.  ***Wikipedia***

[image: Codigo de barras PDF417]

Este es la referencia del Hardware que voy a implementar:

- **Hardware: DS9208 Zebra**

[Visualizar el Hardware](https://www.google.com.co/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0r_uwitfVAhXJLSYKHchGCa0QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zebra.com%2Fla%2Fes%2Fproducts%2Fscanners%2Fgeneral-purpose-scanners%2Fhands-free-on-counter%2Fds9208.html&psig=AFQjCNFWjArDOgLpYNhtL0RmsFuzXYfmSQ&ust=1502812325201555)

Al leer el codigo con el documento de identidad de un ciudadano arroja en un excel todos los datos fijados en celdas(Anteriormente arrojaba los datos en una sola linea, pero como encontre un plugin del mismo hardware se configuro y ahora arroja los datos por celdas, lo que era que buscaba que hiciera):

- 37335083 | 417740 | 1000025047 | HERNANDEZ| PEREZ| MICHAEL | STEVEN| M | 00000000| A¿

Pero al haber solucionado eso, en el navegador al tener digamos varios campos usa el primero para poner la primer variable, el segundo continua en la siguiente pestaña que tenga abierta, y el tercer sigue buscando otro campo, y asi sucesivamente hasta que finalizan las variables), estaba pensando en usar un archivo de excel para subir los datos y pasarle los datos que necesito a la BD, pero no es la solucion ideal que busco, para no depender de un tercero.

> **Nota:** Cabe resaltar que lo que busco es ahorrar tiempo para escribir los datos personales campo a campo, Nombres, Apellidos, Numero, etc. Por ese motivo es que estamos usando este tipo de lectores, para que lo lea y sea insertado en los campos  y solo sea darle al boton para que ejecute la funcion.

***SOLUCIÓN***

Tocó investigar mucho al respecto, leyendo las guias, jugando al prueba y error(realizando las reglas para entender el funcionamiento del hardware por medio del programa de Zebra para configurar Scanners o lectores).

En el siguiente link podrán encontrar el software e incluye unos videos en ingles para poder configurar el scanner:

[Enlace para descargar el software y la documentacion](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ds9208.html)

```
La regla fue :
Toca eliminar las dos primeras reglas, y dejarla de esta forma:

1. Send Extended Key <tab>
2.Send Next <8>
...y el resto de funciones se dejan por defecto.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desactivá el plugin que mencionás: está utilizando internamente combinaciones de teclas como CTRL+TAB para pasar de una celda a otra en Excel, y eso en el navegador se interpreta como cambiar de pestaña.

Hecho esto, poné un TEXTAREA en tu formulario para que el usuario escanee el código de barras, y vuelque el resultado en una sola línea. A continuación usá JavaScript para procesar esa línea, separar los distintos campos, y mostrarlos al usuario (ya sea en una tabla con jQuery, en un párrafo, o como sea).

Más abajo te pongo un ejemplo. Ejecutalo y probá copypasteando una línea completa de PDF417 en el campo de texto.

```js
function procesarPDF417(cadena) {
  var campos = cadena.split("|");
  
  alert(
    "ID: " + campos[0].trim() + "\n" +
    "Apellido: " + campos[3].trim() + "\n" +
    "Nombre: " + campos[5].trim()
   );
}
```

```html
<textarea id="texto" oninput="procesarPDF417(this.value);"></textarea>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Leandro Barone, pero la solucion estaba en un software de la Zebra que sirve para configurar cada lector de dicha empresa. Gracias y creo que vuestra solucion esta bien fundamentada.